# reshape (converting to character)

Tags: r, dcast

i have a the following matrix

```
data=structure(list(Metric = c("x", "y"), Result1 = c(9, 
18), Result2 = c(7, 14
), Delta = c(-170, -401)), .Names = c("Metric", 
"Result_1", "Result_2", "Delta"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to transform it in 1 row and to double the number of columns

I tried the following `(as.vector(t(data)))`. However when I do that it transofrms everything to character and i loose data information

Any help?

Comment: A vector cannot contain more than one classes. Maybe you are just looking for `unlist(data)`?

Comment: this unlist(data) also transforms my data to character

Comment: Oh..nevermind... I thought you wanted a vector. You mean a data frame with just 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data frame and then use `bind_cols` from the `dplyr` package. Although I am not sure this is your expected output as you did not provide any examples, just description.

```
dplyr::bind_cols(split(data, data$Metric))

  Metric Result_1 Result_2 Delta Metric1 Result_11 Result_21 Delta1
1      x        9        7  -170       y        18        14   -401
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base R

```
dd=stack(data)
A=dd$values
names(A)=dd$ind
data.frame(as.list(A))

      Metric Metric.1 Result_1 Result_1.1 Result_2 Result_2.1 Delta Delta.1
1      x        y        9         18        7         14  -170    -401
```